# Search for a word in a Sentence SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have two strings. Need to check if string1 is a substring of string2. It should exactly match a word in the sentence.

String2: `El Alfi Abdullah Ahmed Abdullah`

- Match Scenario: String1: `Ahmed`
- No match Scenario: String1: `Ahme`

```
declare @string2 varchar(max) = 'El Alfi Abdullah Ahmed Abdullah';
declare @string1 varchar(max) = 'Ahmed';
```

Comment: So you're looking for the word, with either it being first in the sentence or preceded by a space, and either ending with a space, non-alpha, or end-of-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using string_split().  **However, this does NOT account for punctuation and such**

```
declare @string2 varchar(max) = 'El Alfi Abdullah Ahmed Abdullah';
declare @string1 varchar(max) = 'Ahmed';

Select hits = count(*)
 From string_split(@string2,' ')
 Where value = @string1
```

**Results**

```
hits
1
```

Now, if `@string1` was `Ahme` ... the `hits` would be 0

Or if you want some simple string manipulation

```
Select sign(charindex(' '+@string1+' ',' '+@string2+' '))  -- returns 1 or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea you could try is to check the lengths after removing string1 from string2 which won't rely on any word boundary:

```
select iif(Len(@string2) - Len(@string1) 
           = Len(Replace(@string2, @string1, '')), 1, 0) IsSubstring;
```